# Pyplot skip data that does not exist in the file

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, charts

How do I skip dates that are not in the data file so pyplot does not have these wide gaps between them?

I would like the gaps to be equal, for example, between 01-06 and 01-09.

Example graph:

[image: Example graph]

My plotting function looks like this atm:

```
def plot_data(data, column_names, width, height, y_max, y_min, x_label, y_label, title, interval, format, precision, markers, colors, legend):
  # Stretching out the graph for better visibility
  plt.figure(figsize = (width, height))

  # Creating line plots; X-axis is for index, Y-axis is for price values
  # Adding labels, colors, markers for each of the plots
  for column_name in column_names:
    plt.plot(data.index, data[column_name], label = column_name, marker = markers[column_names.index(column_name)], color = colors[column_names.index(column_name)])

  # Setting X- and Y- axes labels
  plt.xlabel(x_label)
  plt.ylabel(y_label)

  # Setting title for the graph
  plt.title(title)

  # Enabling grid for the graph
  plt.grid()

  # Enabling legend for the graph
  if(legend == True):
    plt.legend()

  # Setting X-axis limits to start and end of the wanted interval
  plt.xlim(data.index[0], data.index[-1])

  # Adding X-axis ticks for every interval
  plt.xticks(data.index)

  # Formatting the X-axis tick labels to a needed time format
  plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(format)

  # Adjusting the height and precision of Y-axis
  plt.yticks(np.arange(y_min, y_max, step = precision))

  # Automatic rotation of tick labels so they do not overlap
  plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

  # Displaying the graph
  plt.show()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_index_formatter.html